# My dropdown goes crazy

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've the following dropdown:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) dd_HorasImputadas.Items.Add(i.ToString());
```

But when I press one button, the page realoads and dropdown duplicates...

```
Ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 
BUTTON → 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8... 
BUTTON → 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

And every time I push a button (I think it's because the page loads again), numbers doubled again...

Anyone knows how to stop it ? It's like a loop...

I hope I have explained correctly, my English is not very good and I am a novice programmer. Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: Before the loop, clear the existing items in the list!

Comment: Search for IsPostBack property on the Page class

Comment: Listen to Steve, and remember this property, you will need it a lot !

Comment: However if you fall in this trap then I have an advice. Read about [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding items to drop down clear it like this

```
dd_HorasImputadas.Items.Clear();//clears all items of dropdown
```

then add items like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) 
dd_HorasImputadas.Items.Add(i.ToString());
```

Alternate to solution to your problem can be, when you are binding your drop down for the first time include your code in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //this code won't execute if there is any postback like your button click
  for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) 
    dd_HorasImputadas.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press a button, the postback is being triggered, which means the Page_Load function is fired.

Assuming the items are added to the drop down list in the Page_Load function, then every time the page is loaded, the items are added again.

The drop down list needs to be cleared before the items are re-added, which can be done by using:

```
dd_HorasImputadas.Items.Clear();
```

Edit: As other answers mention, you could make use of the

```
Page.IsPostback
```

property.

Answer (score 0):

Call your dropdown fill function like below

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Me.IsPostBack = False Then
       'Fill your dropdown here 
    End If
End Sub
```